# "Last night at 9 PM, I ate dinner" -- Does this sentence mean that it began at 9 or finished at 9?

Tags: prepositions, time

This sentence "Last night at 9 PM, I ate dinner" means that the action began at 9 or finished at 9?

Does it mean that I started eating at 9?

Comment: It refers to start time of dinner, according to me.

Comment: You don't *eat dinner*, you ***have it!***

Comment: I'd say it's none of the above. For me it sounds like you were easting at exactly 9, in other words, at 9 you were putting food in your mouth, probably with a fork

Comment: @MaulikV It's perfectly fine to either eat dinner or have it.

Comment: yes, dinner is something you eat. not sure why one would think "i ate dinner" is unacceptable. it's extremely common, as is "i had dinner".

Comment: While it would be a pretty impressive meal to require to clearly distinguish between the time you start eating and stop eating, if you were to need to explicitely state when you finished dinner, you might say something like "I finished dinner around Nine last night".

Comment: I'd use 'eat dinner' in a different case. Say - *"We are getting late. You are very slow, **eat** your dinner fast"*. Anyway, what do you think about this - I was drinking my tea? @Karen

Comment: @sgroves I did not say that it is *incorrect*. I said, in this context (and in almost all cases), I 'have' dinner is common. About 'eat dinner', I just clarified it in another comment

Comment: Just curious further... is if perfectly fine to ask 'Did you eat your dinner?' too? @Karen considering that 'I eat my dinner'

Comment: You can either eat your dinner or have it, but you can't have your cake and eat it.

Comment: Yes, "Did you eat your dinner?" is fine.

Comment: @MaulikV you said "you don't eat dinner", which i took to mean that you thought it was incorrect. not sure what else you would have meant by that. regardless, "eat dinner" is *just as common* as "have dinner". i say "i ate dinner" all the time, for example.

Answer (score 30):

The use of the preposition *at* specifies a certain *point in time.* Since a meal cannot be eaten in/over/during a *point of time*, the most common way to interpret your sentence

> Last night at 9 PM, I ate dinner

is that you are telling *at what point in time* that dinner **started**.

I cannot stress the following enough:

> It would be **rare to non-existent** for a native speaker to utter your 
>   sentence and refer to 9 PM as the *stopping* point.

We often say sentences like yours (using *at* a specific time) to refer to the starting time of a meal or other event. This is probably so that other people know what time to arrive at the meal or event.

This includes both the past and non-past. Examples with *at* in addition to your sentence include

*Past*
1 Lunch was at 3 yesterday.
2 We had breakfast at 6.
3 They would always eat at noon.

All the above refer to the start time.

*Non-past*
4 Dinner is at 7 tonight.
5 I always eat lunch at 1 pm.
6 At midnight I like to have snack.

Again, the above refer to a *point in time*, and that point in time is the start time.

To indicate the stopping point with *at*, you would usually need to make it clear:

7 Last night I finished my dinner at 9pm.
8 Lunch is over at 12:30. Then you return to class.

---

Note: This answers the question you have actually asked. Note that the speaker of the sentence could have "rounded off" a close time (say 9:05pm) to 9pm, but this does not affect anything about the meaning of the actual sentence the speaker says, using *at*. It only means the speaker was not precise in giving the time.

Changing the prepositional phrase to *around 9pm* changes the meaning of the sentence to *9pm plus or minus about 15 minutes*. But you did not ask about *around 9pm*.

As a side issue, it is not necessary to say *PM* when you specify *last night* since *PM* includes the hour of nine at night.

Comment: I'd also assume it gave the time you _started_ dinner.  As noted in the comments to [Catija's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/74803/22662) the "9" might have been rounded, but it would still mean "_I started eating at 9 [or thereabouts]_".  If you wanted to indicate you were in the _middle_ of dinner, I'd have said "_Last night at 9 PM, I **was eating** dinner_".

Comment: It's also possible that your "dinner" consisted of a snack that only took you under a minute to eat, so in that case it would both start and end at 9.  (Well, 9:00:5x if you want to get technical - people don't generally count the seconds in statements like that.)  I'd still say that some approximation is allowed - not 15 minutes as Catija's answer suggests, but it could easily be up to 5 minutes before or after 9 and still be considered "9 PM".

Comment: I think this answer would have received a lot of downvotes in EL&U because you are giving your primarily opinion-based reply. You never know whether it is a starting time or finishing time or even a time in the middle of dinner. As commented below, you could say you started dinner at 9 even though you started at 8:45 or even 8:30. If you hear people say "I got up at 6", does it mean the time you opened your eyes, you get out of bed, or you start to wash your face? Nobody knows. I downvote your answer and upvote the other which is more objective.

Comment: @Rathony you should refrain yourself from commenting with superfluous words. You downvote, it's fine but don't give your judgement on the answer's credibility is posted elsewhere. An ideal way is -downvote an answer, and give *grammatical* reply though the latter one is optional.

Comment: @MaulikV: I don’t agree with Rathony’s criticisms, but calling them “superfluous words” and saying they should just downvote and reply elsewhere seems a bit harsh.  When someone downvotes an answer *without* commenting, the recipient often asks “Why downvote with no explanation!?” — even if the explanation overlaps with info in other answers, it’s useful to see it here as a counter-point.

Comment: I recommend re-reading my comment! What *is not* superfluous in *"I think this answer would have received a lot ...."* And who said they should downvote and *reply* elsewhere? I said Rathony should not justify answer's credibility by saying 'would have got a lot of downvotes in ELU'. @PLL

Answer (score 19):

As a native speaker, I'd argue that the statement is generic enough to say that the answer is "all of the above".

What this is realistically saying is "Last night, **around** 9 PM, I ate dinner." - meaning that they could have:

- started eating at 8:45 and finished at 9...
- started at 9 and finished at 9:15...
- started at 8:45 and finished at 9:15...
- started eating at 9:15 and ended at 9:30.

There's no real way to know which is "correct" and if the person phrased it this way, it probably doesn't really matter. All they're saying is that, some time during the hour from 9-10 pm, they ate dinner.

If someone wanted to be explicit they would say something more specific like:

> I worked so late last night that I didn't sit down to dinner until 9 pm.
>   There was so much food at the feast that I didn't finish eating dinner until 9 pm!

In these examples, you can clearly see that the action is beginning or ending at 9 pm, respectively.

Comment: If you change the preposition (from *at* to *around*) then yes you change the meaning.

Comment: @NES The point is that when someone says the phrase in the question, it's completely ambiguous what is meant... which is why I changed the preposition, if that's how you want to look at it. I'm talking about actual use, not pure definitions.

Comment: I'm gonna hafta disagree with you on that one.  I don't know anyone who would say, "Last night I ate dinner at 9pm" when they actually started eating at 8:45.  They might say, "I ate at *around* 9pm"  But ***at*** means the starting point.  Now, we don't know whether they put the first forkful of food in their mouth at 9:00, or sat down at at the table at 9:00 or arrived at the restaurant at 9:00 and had to wait for a table or  whether they just left the house to drive to the restaurant at 9:00- that's all ambiguous.

Comment: As another native speaker (UK) if you told me you had dinner at 9 pm I wouldn't find it at all ambiguous,  you started eating at 9pm. It's unlikely to be a problem in this context if you meant around 9 rather than at, but as written in the OP it clearly means started at 9.

Comment: @Jim people round up/down all the time. If I'm talking to a colleague at work and say "I worked so late last night I didn't get to eat dinner until 9pm," I'm speaking in general terms. If I really ate at 8:45 or 9:15, nobody cares. The "around" can be implied, because not everyone treats every claim as something that must be perfectly backed up. If you were telling the police your whereabouts as they questioned you, omitting the "around" might be a bigger deal.

Comment: @NES I think this depends a lot on context. If I'm telling someone when dinner is going to be I am sure to use **at** to mean the (earliest time) when it will start, because that's the information they need. If I'm being asked by a cop when I ate dinner yesterday I'm sure to use **around** since I don't usually check the clock when I sit down to dinner. Best I can do will be a time window of roughly 15-30 minutes. If I'm talking with a colleague about when I tend to have dinner I'd probably use **at** and would round to the closest hour, since noone cares about 5 minutes one way or the other.

Comment: @Jim I would not hear “9 pm” in a sentence like this as being all that precise. I would accept that sentence as accurate even if the dinner itself was eaten entirely between 8:45 and 8:55, because it’s close enough to 9 pm for this purpose. Similarly, “we’ll leave at 11” can easily mean not actually getting out the door until 11:15, 11:30. In casual conversation those times just don’t offer much precision.

Comment: @KRyan- It appears that this varies greatly from person to person.  For me, If I mentioned *at 9:00* I probably apply at most a +/-5 min tolerance, but the activity would need to be occurring at 9:00- in other words- if I was eating between 8:45 and 8:55 then I would *never* say, "I ate at 9:00" I'd say I ate *just before 9:00* or "I didn't eat until almost 9:00" And if I wanted to be a bit imprecise I'd use *around*- I ate *around 9:00 last night*."  Using *at* for me ***means*** precision.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer as nobody knows what the speaker has in mind when he says "I ate dinner at 9". Nobody checks the time when he starts dinner or finishes it. It is just around 9.

Comment: I agree with this but only because it was 9:00, I would say it really means "I was eating last night around 9:00 because of the "Rounded" nature of the time.  If someone said "I ate dinner last night at 9:04" that would certainly be the time they started eating.  Also if it is an invitation "We will be eating at 9:00" then you should expect to eat soon after 9:00, probably 9:15-9:30 depended on expected level of socializing.  If you are invited to "A Dinner" at 8:00, you may not eat until 9:00, at that point the word Dinner may represent an entire night's activities.

Comment: It depends on the context. If you're telling a friend about your day, nobody cares that much, nor does anybody remember the exact time they ate, so you might use "at" and still be rather imprecise. If you're inviting a friend to a party "at 9:00," you may mean the party starts at 9:00, but social custom may dictate that he arrive "fashionably late." And if you arrange for a flyby of military fighter jets "at 9:00pm," you'll get fighter jets at 9:00:00 on the dot.

Comment: @ZachLipton- "*Does anyone remember the exact time they ate?*" ***No.*** But in that case I'd say, "I ate ***at around*** 9:00" or "I ate at 9:00 ***-ish***"  Anyway. I think it's good to provide alternate points of view on this.  And now that I've done that. I'm out...

Comment: I think you go to far and play fast and loose wit the language unwarrantedly. The given sentence is far more precise than you suggest. In particular, "Dinner from 9:15 - 9:30" could not possibly fit, that would require saying something more like "around 9". English is very particular about when, where, how, and its use of prepositions, and you would be misleading people if you used "at" to mean anything other than within a few minutes of 9.

Answer (score 4):

> Last night at 9PM, I ate dinner.

Start.

> Last night at 9PM, I finished eating dinner.

End.

> Last night at 9PM, I had eaten dinner.

End or later.

> Last night at 9PM, I was eating dinner.

Some time during the dinner.

> Last night at 9PM, I had been eating dinner.

Some time during the dinner when an interruption occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say that [telicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity) is involved here.

[On the other hand I don't think the use of light verbs (*e.g.*, *have* for *eat*) matters in this case.]

Compare  the following sentences:

> *I conquered Elbonia *for* three days.
>
> I conquered Elbonia *in* three days.

*Eating* or *to eat* ***is not*** a necessarily complete act.

*Eating a meal* or *to eat a meal* ***is*** necessarily a complete act. Otherwise you would only be eating *part of the meal*.

Notice that we would have to switch to a continuous or progressive description (or change the tense entirely) in order to be able to indicate anything other than the time at which the meal occurred.

> I *was eating* around nine o'clock.

However we are considering the entire, complete act.  In some sense it isn't relevant when it begins and ends--precisely because it is complete and self-contained.  Thus it is unnecessary to force *the beginning alone* to be aligned with the time mentioned.

> I *ate at* nine.
>
> I *did eat at* nine.

These statements include all the information we need to understand the time of occurrence because they force us to consider the meal *as an **event*** taking place ***at*** a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting sentence. It's the answer that I would give if I was asked "what did you do yesterday at precisely 9 PM?". In that case the answer would mean "At precisely 9 PM, I was eating. So most likely I started before 9 PM and finished after 9 PM, unless I took my very first or very last bite at exactly 9 PM".

On the other hand, if I said "at 8 PM, I came home from work. At 8:30 I had a shower, and at 9 PM I had dinner" - then it would mean that the shower started at 8:30, and the dinner started at 9 PM. It all depends on the context.

Answer (score -1):

I think this sentence has an uncertainty which shows the person might have started his dinner somewhere around 9 PM, so he is not sure but he somehow manages to remember time while he was having dinner or after finishing his dinner.